# Нужно ли тире в предложении? (2)

Tags: пунктуация, тире

Нужно ли тире в данном предложении?

*Вертится волчком, катится бочком.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Информация о предложении.
Это загадка. И это неполное предложение, так как отсутствует подлежащее.
[Что-то] Вертится волчком, катится бочком.

Информация из словарей.
[Вертеться волчком](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F+%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC) — очень быстро кружиться.
[Катиться](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F)
**1.** Вращаясь, двигаться, перемещаться в каком-либо одном направлении (об округлых предметах). *Катились деревянные шары, сбивая расставленные кегли. Со звоном катится по асфальту железный обруч.*

Информация о [юле](https://tatmuseum.ru/news/muzejnaya-azbuka-yu-yula_2018_08_16/).
Она может вращаться в вертикальном положении достаточно долго: до тех пор, пока трение точки опоры о поверхность не замедлит вращение. После этого юла **падает на бок**, но некоторое время еще продолжает кручение-качение уже на бочине. То есть катится по-особенному, не по определению, а бочком.

Информация из справочника Розенталя ([интонационное тире](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=91#pp91)):

> Тире ставится для указания места разделения простого предложения на словесные группы, чтобы подчеркнуть либо уточнить смысловые отношения между членами предложения, когда другими знаками препинания или порядком слов нужный смысл не может быть выражен...
> Такое тире, **называемое интонационным**, может отделять любую часть предложения...

Итожим: тире ставится, думаю, для того, чтобы обозначить *загадочную* паузу и акцентировать внимание на нестандартном использовании глагола "катиться".

**Вертится волчком, катится — бочком.**

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо за вопрос, а Римме – спасибо за ответ.

Удивительно, но у меня постановка тире тоже **вызвала сомнения**. Симметрия фразы показалась нарушенной, что нехарактерно для этого устного народного  жанра.

Загадка есть загадка,  **лишние подсказки** здесь не нужны.  Поискала варианты без тире, но их не было. В каком же сборнике впервые появилась загадка, неужели и там стояло тире?

Но найти что-либо  на эту тему тоже,  к сожалению,  не удалось,  а было бы интересно (ну просто конкурсный вопрос!).

И несколько слов **про интонационное тире**.

Интонационное тире – это не только пауза, но и другая расстановка ударений:

***Вертится волчкОм,  кАтится — бочком.*** Ударение с обстоятельства переходит на сказуемое и логически подчеркивает его.